# After including PHP tags The navbar is not collapsing

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just include this php tags just to check,that if the user is logged in or not.The modal is located in other page(login.php) . It was working fine without including the php tags."The whole thing is working fine except the navbar is not collapsing".Rate +ve if the question is not irrelevant.

```
          <div class="navbar-header">
          <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collmenu"> 
             <span class="icon-bar img-reponsive"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar img-reponsive"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar img-reponsive"></span>
         </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse collmenu">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <?php
         if(!empty($loggedin)&&($loggedin=='true')){ echo'<li><a href="">logout</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">hello</a></li>';}

            else{echo'<li><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginmodal">Login</a></li>
                 <li><a href="pages/register.php">Signup</a></li>';}

        ?>  
            </ul>

  </div>
```

Comment: Your problem must be somewhere else, the PHP would not affect the navbar collapsing.

Comment: Where do you think it can be. @WheatBeak

Comment: Don't know, did you check your browser console for javascript errors?

Comment: no errors at all in the console @WheatBeak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check for the files that you've included.
Or is there any form exists in your this page linked to the navbar?
check that you should not have included files twice, also check for the form action if any.

Comment: actually yes it did work, the form was posting to the same file that i've required.